# How many integer solutions of $2^x+3^y-7n=0,~n \in \mathbb Z$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation $2^x+3^y=7n,~n \in \mathbb Z$.

> How many integer (positive) solutions are there for this equation? Can it have infinitely many positive integer solutions?
>
> What is an example of a positive rational solution?

---

To reduce the number of variables, we fix $x$ as follows:

Fix $x=3$, then the equation becomes $$2^3+3^y=7n \Rightarrow 3^y=7n-8 \Rightarrow 3^y=27\Rightarrow y=3,$$ taking $n=5$. So $(3,3)$ is an integer solution.  Is there other integer solutions for other $n$ ?

So when $x=3$, we can draw $3^y=7z-8$ and see the graph is asymptotic in nature. I doubt there is other positive integer solution.

If we fix $x=5$, then the equation becomes $$2^5+3^y=7n \Rightarrow 3^y=7n-32 \Rightarrow 3^y=3\Rightarrow y=3,$$ taking $n=1$. So $(5,1)$ is an integer solution. Again, if we draw the curve $3^y=7z-32$ and see it is asymptotic in nature. I doubt there is other positive integer solution except $(5,1)$.

My intuition says, if we fix $x$ to be positive integer, then $y$ can take only one positive integer. There might be positive rational solution, but I don't know off them.

Therefore the equation $2^x+3^y=7n,~n \in \mathbb Z$ and $x,y \in \mathbb N$ has "countably" many solutions, for each $x \in \mathbb N$ there is only one $y \in \mathbb N$.

Are there any examples of positive rational solutions that are not integer solutions?

I appreciate your answer.

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: If there is one integer solution, then there must be infinite many because the residues of $2^x$ and $3^y$ mod $7$ cycle. No idea whether there is a non-integer rational solution.

Comment: @Peter, woh, thank you for using congruence property. But still I don't have clue with non-integer rational solutions

Comment: The easiest to spot integer solution is $(x,y)=(2,1)$

Comment: Also, for every $x$ (for which there is a solution at all) , there are infinite many $y$ doing the job , not just one.

Comment: @Peter, Thank you for $(2,1)$ as well as for your last useful comment. I got it

Comment: What do you mean by a rational solution? For any pair of integers $x$ and $y$ there is a unique rational $n$ such that $2^x+3^y=7n$. If either $x$ or $y$ is rational (but not integral) then $n$ cannot be rational because $\sqrt[k]{2}$ and $\sqrt[m]{3}$ are independent over $\Bbb{Q}$ for all integers $k,m>1$.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump., the equation is $2^x+3^y \equiv 0$ (mod$~7$). My question was whether $x,y \in \mathbb Q^{>0} \setminus \mathbb Z^{>0}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting the equation in modulo 7, we have
$$3^y\equiv -2^x \quad  \pmod 7 $$
Noting that $2^3\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod 7$, we get $3$ cases for $x$,
$\quad $ A.  $x=3h$,$ \quad $  B. $x=3k+1 \quad  $  and $\quad $ C. $3k+2$.

A. When $x=3h, $
$$
3^y \equiv-(2^{3}) ^h\equiv-1  \equiv 6 \quad  \pmod 7
$$
By the Fermat Little Theorem, $3^6\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod 7 $, we have
$$3^{6 m+3} \equiv  \left(3^6\right)^m \cdot 3^3 \equiv  1^m \cdot 3^3
\equiv 6 \quad  \pmod 7 
$$
Therefore $y=6m+3$.

---

B. When $x=3k+1, $
$$
3^y \equiv-2(2^{3}) ^k  \equiv-2  \equiv 5 \quad  \pmod 7
$$
By the Fermat Little Theorem, $3^6\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod 7 $, we have
$$3^{6 m+5} \equiv  \left(3^6\right)^m \cdot 3^5 \equiv  1^m \cdot 3^5
\equiv 5 \quad  \pmod 7 
$$
Therefore $y=6m+5$.

---

C. When $x=3k+2, $
$$
3^y \equiv-4(2^{3}) ^k  \equiv-4  \equiv 3 \quad  \pmod 7
$$
By the Fermat Little Theorem, $3^6\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod 7 $, we have
$$3^{6 m+1} \equiv  \left(3^6\right)^m \cdot 3\equiv  1^m \cdot 3
\equiv 3 \quad  \pmod 7 
$$
Therefore $y=6m+1$.

---

We now can conclude that there are infinitely many integer solutions $(x,y,n)$ which are

$$
\boxed{\left(3 h, 6 m+3 , \frac{2^{3 h}+3^{6 m+3}}{7}\right), 
\left(3 k+1,6 m+5, \frac{ 2^{3 k+1}+3^{6 m+5}}{7} \right) \quad  \textrm{ and } 
\left(3 k+2, 6m+1, \frac{2^{3k+2}+3^{6k+1}}{7}\right) }
$$
where $h\in N$ and $k,m \in N \cup\{0\}.$

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Now I want to see if there any non-integer rational solutions ?

Comment: I guess there is no non-integer rational solution!

Comment: yes I agree intuitively but we need to show a contradiction